# Low request per second from Laravel, Docker, and AWS combination

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, docker, architecture

- Laravel 5.5
- Php 7.0
- AWS 8 cpu / 16GB
- Docker with nginx/php inside.

I have an api that serves oauth2.0 via passport. It was working fine for low volume traffic but since we have ramped up traffic it buckled. We have a docker application on an EC2 machine with 8 cpu / 16gb ram / SSD.
All it the api serves is email/password/client_id/client_secret check, then write the token into the DB, and the user data inside a redis store. (2 read / 2 writes / 1 write to redis). It returns a JWT access_token and a refresh_token (plus the ttl)

The laravel application is dockerized via an ubuntu docker + nginx + 7.0php-fpm with the necessary extensions. (its the same dockerize that Chris Fidao created in his series shippingwithdocker)

I ran locust.io server (on another ec2 machine on AWS) testing at 200 users / 10 hatch/sec and 100% cpu utilization on all cores. 
If i increase it to 255ish - I start having some 502 bad gateways. I check the php log and php-fpm is unable to service anymore calls. I made a tweak to the php-fpm.conf file: pm = ondemand with 200 children, 1000 max request. I am able to achieve 300 more users at 15 hatch/sec 100% cpu utilization. As another test - what i have done is taken the RAW read DB query + raw insert query and removed redis writting - simply wrote it as part of the routes/api.php closure and let it ripped. I managed to get up to 500 users approx with 134 request/second (no controllers)

My question is:
does these metrics seems wrong to anyone? I have an 8 core / 16GB and im getting a low throughput?
after finding Taylor Otwell's [blog](https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/benchmarking-laravel-symfony-zend-2c01c2b270f8) about how he manage to hit 500+ request/sec with a 2GB ram machine on Digital Ocean - is there a setting that I should be checking?
I am just trying to ensure that this is my final benchmark metrics and effectively in order to receive more request - I should add another server under a load balancer.

**UPDATE #1**

1. we use mysql 5.7 (RDS) for the queries and it is 4 queries as i mentioned 2 R /2 W and 1 to redis which is an elasticache instance
2. the median (ms)  is 340ms according to locust.io

**UPDATE #2**
For those who are asking for htop metrics underload
[image: htop screen]

**Update #3**
- enabled `route:cache`
- enabled `config:cache`
checked that the docker had Zend OPCache on
[image: opcache enabled confirm]
[image: settings]
no improvement unfortunately.

Comment: Do you use an RDBMS? Are you sure it takes 5 queries for one single api call? Do you know how long does TTFB take?

Comment: What is the average response time per API? Enable profiling.

Comment: @ValerianPereira - i have added the median to my response. i have already profiled it and the above is the result.

Comment: @revo see the above edit for your questions

Comment: Start to monitor queries and log slow ones to get into the bottleneck if queries are the culprits by any chance.

Comment: @revo its not a query problem. running each query on 2M records yield less than 0.1s on first hit and 0.00s on subsequential hit  - also as i mentioned php-fpm is the one that stops responding.

Comment: Did you find anything useful?

Comment: @revo - nothing as of yet except that everyone believes the same as me which is an abnormality happenning